# Feature parameter in YouTube embed link

Tags: youtube, embed

What is the purpose of using "feature" parameter in YouYube embed link?

The video is working fine if I use below embed tag,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRFnsOUoHmM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when I changed the `src` value to `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRFnsOUoHmM&feature=g-upl`, the video won’t play. I have added the parameter `feature=g-upl` in this link.

I can’t understand the purpose of this parameter. And why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

There is no purpose to using the feature parameter in a YouTube embed link nor do I think you should be using that when embedding. When embedding a video YouTube actually has a different URL they use in the src field.

**For example** with the video link you are using your src field would use this url: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/275VsDVauN8`

When on the video's page you can click `share` and then `embed` and be presented with the options for embedding and the code you would insert into your html document to embed the video (see image below)

[image: example]

Using this tool on the share page should provide you with what you need to embed the right way. The feature parameter is not used in embedding.